# Qt: Is waitForReadyRead/waitForBytesWritten necessary in a synchronous UDP socket?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

The QUDPSocket can be used without a event loop in a sync mode.
And I found the example below:

```
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QTextStream>

int main()
{
    QTextStream qout(stdout);

    QUdpSocket *udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(0);
    udpSocket->bind(3838, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);

    while (udpSocket->waitForReadyRead(-1)) {
        while(udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
            QByteArray datagram;
            datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
            QHostAddress sender;
            quint16 senderPort;

            udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),
                                    &sender, &senderPort);
            qout << "datagram received from " << sender.toString() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: Is waitForReadyRead necessary here? Can I use a while(1) instead if I am not worrying about the CPU consumption?
If I need to write, is it necessary to add a waitForBytesWritten?

I used to work with TCP sockets in sync mode under Qt, it does not work at all without the waitForReadyRead call.

Comment: `QAbstractSocket` documentation states that calling `waitForReadyRead` is necessary for reading and calling `waitForBytesWritten` is necessary for flushing written changes in synchronous mode. `QTcpSocket` and `QUdpSocket` don't seem to have differences.

Comment: But some one said that QUDPSocket is actually unbuffered, so there is no need to wait, since the application is talking to OS's buffere directly?

Comment: That may be true, but the documentation doesn't say that, so it's risky. You can read `QUdpSocket` source to verify that.

Comment: Yeah, I am just curious how they can be used in sync mode

Comment: I cannot see any advantage in omitting the call to `waitForReadyRead()`.  You'll make your program very CPU-inefficient, and won't gain any compensating benefit by doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The sockets internally use non-interrupting platform notfications, and these only fire when the event loop *or* a `waitFor...` method has control of the thread. Your choices are:

1. Write asynchronous code using C++11 lambdas/closures to keep the code concise without need for explicit helper objects. Or write Qt 4-style async code with explicit `QObject`s that provide handler slots.
2. Write pseudosynchronous code using `waitFor...` methods, with the caveat that some methods of `QObject`s running on the same thread may need to be reentrant.
3. Use native networking APIs.